# How i know how many user accessing the website

Tags: java

I have to show how many people are online in that site. The site has developed j2ee (jsp and servlet). How can i do that???

Comment: Seriously? When asking questions and wondering what detail to include, it helps to pretend that we can't see your system/website or read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

With the lack of details, any suggestion we might have for how you could accomplish this yourself would just be a shot in the dark.

What you should do is ask the developer/vendor of the e-commerce application.

Comment: Actually I am developing ecommerce application in j2ee(Jsp,Servlet) technology. In that I need to write the code which inform me how many users are accessing the website.

Comment: Are you kidding?

Comment: I dont find any kidding short of thing here . This question is being asked by other people in stack overflow. The url of the link is "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890820/find-out-how-many-users-are-online-in-php" . But i want this in j2ee. If u dont know the answer . don't comment

Comment: @Wahid I don't think mc9x was trying to be offensive. Your question was very broad. If you are using a framework to develop this application, you should probably ask over at StackOverflow. Best of luck sir/ma'm.